# ASCII encoding for String using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, encoding, ascii

What I need to do is Convert a String to byte array with ASCII encoding…
I’m using Swift and I can see the utf-8, utf-16 and unicodeScalars but no Ascii encoding found for String.

How can I do it?
For example for a string like “ID00000004” the content of the bytes should be “49443030303030303034”

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: For all characters in the ASCII character set (U+0000 .. U+007F), the UTF-8 encoding and the ASCII encoding are *identical*.

Comment: @MartinR You may want to post your earlier comment as an answer, given that the answer it was posted on has been deleted.

Comment: Hi,
Yes, it's true but the result is not the correct one... I'm new with swift so maybe I'm doing the things wrong...

I tried as follow:

var ID_Centrale : [Byte] = [UInt8](myString.utf8)

but the result is "73684848484848484852" instead of "49443030303030303034"

I tried also this code:

var ID_Centrale = [Byte]()
for char in centrale.id_centrale.utf8{
    ID_Centrale += [char]
}

Why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the following code is correct, the result was printed in console in decimal instead of hex

var result : [Byte] = UInt8

Thank you